# If the first statement in a for comprehension fails , recover is not able to catch the exception

Tags: scala

I am struggling to understand the for comprehension and exception handling in Scala.

If the first statement in a for comprehension fails , recover is not able to catch the exception.

Code where recover catches the exception successfully(Exception thrown in 2nd statement):

```
import scala.util.{Success, Try}

object ExceptionThrownIn2ndStatement {
  def failTryUnit(x: Unit): Try[Int] = {
    println(x)
    val a = 1 / 0
    new Success(a)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    (for {
      var0 <- Try(println("Zeroth function"))
      varFailure <- failTryUnit(var0) //exception thrown here
      var1 <- Try(println("first function", varFailure))
    } yield var1) recover { case e =>
      println("Exception caught", e) //exception caught here
    }
  }
}
```

Output :

```
Zeroth function
()
(Exception caught,java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero)
```

Code where recover does NOT catch the exception successfully :

```
import scala.util.{Success, Try}

object ExceptionThrownIn1stStatement {
  def failTryUnit(x: Unit): Try[Int] = {
    println(x)
    val a = 1 / 0
    new Success(a)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    (for {
      varFailure <- failTryUnit({}) //exception thrown here
      var0 <- Try(println("zeroth function", varFailure))
      var1 <- Try(println("first function", var0))
    } yield var1) recover { case e =>
      println("Exception caught",e) //Exception does not get caught here
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
()
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at ExceptionThrownIn1stStatement$.failTryUnit(ExceptionThrownIn1stStatement.scala:6)
    at ExceptionThrownIn1stStatement$.main(ExceptionThrownIn1stStatement.scala:12)
    at ExceptionThrownIn1stStatement.main(ExceptionThrownIn1stStatement.scala)
```

Edit : I understand that this is not the way recover is supposed to be used. 
I am just confused as to why this happens. Please help me understand this. I am new to Scala.

Comment: What is the type signature and definition of `failTryUnit` ?, Also, what exactly do you mean whit the exception does not get caught?, what is the type and result value of your for in both cases? - BTW, do you know that calling `recover` with an computation that returns `Unit` _(like a println)_ is not the intended use case?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez why is "not an intended use case"?

Comment: @Dima Well given the name and the type signature, the function is to _recover_ from a **failure** providing a **successful** value _(which a `Unit` is not)_. Also, that would give you a `Try[Any]` which is very usable IMHO. - Now, I would agree that, given there is no other method to operate only in errors, and if your Try will not return any value, but just do some side-effecting operation, it seems more readable that doing a pattern matching just to log the error _(that is what I would do)_ - But, I think we will end up talking about personal preferences, so I will just give you a point. :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez how is Unit is "not successful"? And why would it give you a `Try[Any]` if the main branch is returning a `Unit` too?

Comment: @Dime Sorry if not made myself clear, I meant to say that if your main branch is a `Unit`, or if you don't care for any result but for the side effects, the it is perfectly OK. And I don't wanted to say that an `Unit` is not a **success**, rather I wanted to say it is not a **_"value"_**, - in the sense that if I had a `Try`, of let's say `Int`, using `recover` with a `println`, will gave me a `Try[Any]` _(`AnyVal` in this particular example)_ which will not be useful _(at least not for me)_ on a chained computation where the next stage depends on the output of the previous. Hope I was clearer

Comment: @purpleRaincoat, I am unable to recreate the conditions you've described. A more complete code example is needed.

Comment: I have updated the post with complete code now. Can someone help me understand why is this happening? What is happening behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a shorter example that demonstrates the same behavior:

```
Success(42).flatMap(x => { assert(false); Success(x + 58) })
```

vs.

```
{ assert(false); Success(42) }.flatMap(x => Success(x + 58))
```

The first one will return a `Failure` with a caught error. The second one will crash with an `AssertionError`.

The first returns a `Failure` because that's the semantics of `Try`s `flatMap` - it catches all exceptions that occur during the execution of the function passed to it.

The second one crashes immediately, because the very first statement is an `assert(false)`, so you never get to the point where you construct a `Try` in the first place, the `AssertionError` is thrown before the first `Success` constructor is invoked. It wouldn't matter whether you append more `recover`s on it or not - no `Try` will ever be instantiated in this program.

Here is what you would have to do to catch the exception occurring during the very first calculation (`42`):

```
Try { assert(false); 42 }.flatMap(x => Success(x + 58))
```

In your code, that would be

```
def failTryUnit(x: Unit): Try[Int] = Try {
  println(x)
  1 / 0
}
```